# Como remover o valor da ultima posição do TextBox com o Substring?

Tags: c#, .net, string

Como remover o valor da ultima posição do `TextBox` com o `Substring`?

Suponhamos que o `TextBox` receba um valor com essa **mascara = 0,00%**, contudo, só quero salvar os números e não o carácter porcento, como é que faço?

Comment: É um `textbox` ou um `maskedTextbox`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Partindo do princípio que realmente só o último `%`, que nada foi digitado errado, e normalmente algo pode ser, muita coisa pode dar errado se não estiver como espera, e validar tudo dá trabalho, aí seria isto:

```
texto = texto.TrimEnd('%');
```

Se quiser o último, não importa o que:

```
texto = texto.Substring(0, texto.Length - 1);
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/String/TrimSubstr.cs).

Comment: Muito obrigado Maniero, resolveu.

Answer (score 2):

Você também pode usar o **Replace** para retirar da sua String algum sinal ou caractere.

Suponhamos:

```
String texto = "0,00%";

// Retirando o sinal de porcentagem
texto = texto.Replace("%","");
Resultado: 0,00

// Retirando a virgula
texto = texto.Replace(",","");
Resultado; 000%

//retirando a virgula e o sinal de porcentagem
texto = texto.Replace("%","").Replace(",","");
Resultado: 000
```

O **Replace** troca o que está entre as duas primeiras aspas pelo que está entre as duas últimas aspas = .Replace(**"primeira"**,**"última"**)

Você pode usar o **Replace** várias vezes de forma encadeada na mesma string.